# jquery position().left sometime return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i know the question **jquery position left return 0** asked too many times, **but** in my case it works in 90% and in the other 10% it return 0.

here is my case:

i use css multi-column to show my html file, the html content is dynamic and i add more content in some condition, i use `insertBefore` for adding my content.

here is my code for adding more content:

```
addString = function(s)
    {
        $(s).insertBefore('#endMarker');
        _columnCount = Math.floor($('#endMarker').position().left/(_windowWidth + _columnGap));

        if(_columnCount < 0)
        {
            rtl = 1;
            _columnCount = (_columnCount * -1);
            informRTL(rtl);
        }
        reportNumberOfPage(_columnCount);

    };
```

`endMarker` is an span at the end of html.

so sometime i get `0` for `_columnCount` and in other case it produce the right number.

tnx in advance.

Comment: is the DOM ready before you call this?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey  : before calling this function? i think so. after calling `insertBefore`, i'm not sure. sorry i'm not a `javascript` programmer, but i know you mean something like `document ready`, yes?

Comment: we'd have to know what else is changing and how this is called. If it is called before the DOM is laid out, or if position style attribute is changing of the parent, things can change.

Comment: ok, first you must know that column width is `$( window ).innerWidth()`, so each column fill width of screen and i use the column number to show other columns, when i add more content? when the user reach the last column, nothing change in parent, just adding more tag to body.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey : here is another info, if i add `<p>  </p>` after each element and then add it to page, the chance of success goes up to 95%, but i can figure out whats happening in other case, any suggestion?

Comment: you'd need to post all your files. or use jsfiddle and set up a reproducible case.

Comment: the code is too large (it's an app in android and html file retrieved in java and split into element via `Jsoup`), tell me witch part is important to you?

Comment: most important is the HTML around #endMarker and where you call addString